# What is the relationship between winutils and HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

HBase Java client API connects Hbase, I know how to fix this:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:382) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.7.jar:?]
```

but I want to know, why HBase cares about a system dependent binary thing, why not connect HBase directly in Java code, and why there is no official documentation mention about this point out there [google search link on Apache site](https://www.google.com/search?q=hbase%20%22winutils%22%20site:apache.org)

Answer (score 0):

There's no official documentation because Hadoop doesn't support Windows.

Take a look at http://www.hadoopathome.co.uk/Running-HBase-Testing-Utility-On-Windows/ (my personal blog) and https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils.

Comment: awesome, and why not connect hbase in java code, why do we have to connect via system utility?